# start an existing instance with specific instanceID through code in Amazon ec2

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to start an existing instance with a specific instanceID, not the imageID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have an EBS backed instance that you previously stopped, you can start it again via the API with the same instance ID that it had previously - see http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-StartInstances.html

If you want to specify an instance ID when you create a new EC2 instance, I'm pretty sure that is not possible.